# AutoFill to end of sheet from middle of sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a template that once used can have any number of rows. The biggest problem I have is my data does not start until A32. There is information above this line but not relevant to the Macro. The macro will be entering in the formulas and I need it to Auto Fill down to the last row. I can get it to work when I started at row 1 in a test sheet, but not so much when moved to line 32.

```
Range("U32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]=""CM"", -RC[-8],RC[-8])"
Range("V32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-13],Sheet1!R80C7:R1048576C7,1,FALSE),"""")"
Range("W32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  ="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-14],Sheet2!R80C7:R1048576C7,1,FALSE),"""")"
Range("X32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]<>"""", CONCATENATE('Recon _
  Form'!R2C23,'Recon Form'!R4C23,'Recon Form'!R3C23,'Recon _
  Form'!R5C23,RC[1]),"""")"
Range("Y32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-16]="""","""",IF(RC[-3]<>"""",""Sheet1 "", 
IF(RC[-2]<>"""",""Sheet2 "", IF(RC[1]<>"""",""Sheet4 "", _
  IF(RC[2]<>"""",""Sheet3 "", ""REVIEW"")))))"
Range("Z32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-17],Sheet4!R159C4:R1048576C4,1,FALSE),"""")"
Range("AA32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-18],Sheet3!R159C4:R1048576C4,1,FALSE),"""")"
Range("A32:AA32").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A32:AA" & _
  Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)`
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to activate each cell; you should be able to use Range("U32").FormularR1C1 = ...... which will greatly reduce the amount of code, and speed things up.

Comment: What does "not so much" mean?

Comment: It enters the formulas but does not auto fill down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the selects and with R1C1, one does not need fill down, just assign directly.

```
Dim LRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range(.Cells(32, 21), .Cells(LRow, 21)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-13]=""CM"", -RC[-8],RC[-8])"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 22), .Cells(LRow, 22)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-13],Sheet1!R80C7:R1048576C7,1,FALSE),"""")"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 23), .Cells(LRow, 23)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-14],Sheet2!R80C7:R1048576C7,1,FALSE),"""")"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 24), .Cells(LRow, 24)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[1]<>"""", CONCATENATE('Recon Form '!R2C23,'Recon Form'!R4C23," & _
        "'Recon Form'!R3C23,'Recon Form '!R5C23,RC[1]),"""")"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 25), .Cells(LRow, 25)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-16]="""","""",IF(RC[-3]<>"""",""Sheet1 "", IF(RC[-2]<>""""," & _
        """Sheet2 "", IF(RC[1]<>"""",""Sheet4 "", IF(RC[2]<>"""",""Sheet3 "", ""REVIEW"")))))"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 26), .Cells(LRow, 26)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-17],Sheet4!R159C4:R1048576C4,1,FALSE),"""")"

    .Range(.Cells(32, 27), .Cells(LRow, 27)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-18],Sheet3!R159C4:R1048576C4,1,FALSE),"""")"

    .Range("A32:T32").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A32:T" & LRow)
End With
```